# Django не может подключится к postgres

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть docker-compose.yml, который запускает три контейнера: frontend, backend и database.
После старта контейнеров, фронтенд доступен, но джанго не может подключиться к базе, вылетает ошибка:

```
 Is the server running on host "database" (10.254.0.2) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

После того, как я перезагружу контейнер с джангой (docker restart f6aea49c798e), все взлетает и интерфейс джанги отвечает. В момент проблемы, если провалиться в контейнер с джангой, пинг до базы работает, и телнет 5432 тоже.
Что я делаю не так? Ниже мой docker-compose файл. Я пробовал выставлять depends_on, пробовал делать health-check, как видите ниже.

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS

```
    PORTS                                       NAMES
f6aea49c798e   localhost:5000/backend    "python manage.py ru…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours             0.0.0.0:8181->8000/tcp, :::8181->8000/tcp   backend
53116b53c03a   postgres:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   database
e0b379a85516   localhost:5000/frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours             0.0.0.0:81->3000/tcp, :::81->3000/tcp       frontend
cc7d032bf271   registry:2                "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   27 hours ago   Up 27 hours             0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   registry



---
services:
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: frontend
    image: localhost:5000/frontend
    tty: True
    ports:
      - 81:3000

  backend:
    restart: always
    container_name: backend
    image: localhost:5000/backend
    ports:
      - 8181:8000
    networks:
      - back
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: database
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: django
      POSTGRES_USER: django
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: django
    networks:
      - back
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U django"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

networks:
  back:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.254.0.0/24
          gateway: 10.254.0.1
          aux_addresses:
            db: 10.254.0.10
            backend: 10.254.0.20
```

Если просто пытаюсь запустить конейнеры без компоса, то происхолдит тоже самое.

```
docker network create --subnet 10.100.0.0/24 --ip-range 10.100.0.0/24 myNetwork 
docker run -td --name database --network=myNetwork -p 5432:5432 localhost:5000/postgres
docker run -td --name django --network=myNetwork -p 8181:8000 localhost:5000/backend
```